# How to get current k8s context name using client-go

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go

I am trying to get / print the name of my current `kubernetes` context as it is configured in `~/.kube/config` using `client-go`

I hava managed to authenticate and get the `*rest.Config` object

```golang
    config, err = clientcmd.NewNonInteractiveDeferredLoadingClientConfig(
        &clientcmd.ClientConfigLoadingRules{ExplicitPath: pathToKubeConfig},
        &clientcmd.ConfigOverrides{
            CurrentContext: "",
        }).ClientConfig()
```

but I don't see any relevant fields in the `config` struct.

Note that despite the fact I am passing an empty string (`""`) in the `ConfigOverrides` the `config` object returned provides me a `kubernetes.Clientset` that is based on my current `kubectl` context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The function `ClientConfig()` returns the Kubernetes API client config, so it has no information about your config file.

To get the current context, you need to call `RawConfig()`, then there is a field called `CurrentContext`.

The following code should work.

```golang
    config, err := clientcmd.NewNonInteractiveDeferredLoadingClientConfig(
        &clientcmd.ClientConfigLoadingRules{ExplicitPath: pathToKubeConfig},
        &clientcmd.ConfigOverrides{
            CurrentContext: "",
        }).RawConfig()
    currentContext := config.CurrentContext
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Get your current context like this too easily using the `GetConfigFromFileOrDie` method

Once the Config is loaded - you can get the current context with `config.CurrentContext`

```
kubeconfig := filepath.Join(os.Getenv("HOME"), ".kube", "config")


if config := clientcmd.GetConfigFromFileOrDie(kubeconfig); conf != nil{
    fmt.Println("Current Context is",config.CurrentContext)
}
```

Further reference on this method is [here](https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd#GetConfigFromFileOrDie)